# Can't manage to run 2-player Python game

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I tried to do game(actually at least to run it on my computer) that I saw in one tutorial. Unfortunately, their forum is not frequently visited, so maybe here I can found the solution.

But when I try to run it on different computers, which are connected to one Wi-fi, client on the second computer(local server is on the first) doesn't find server:
I do this way:

```
Start server and set to localhost:8000
Start the first client and type localhost:8000, after what it connects to server
In cmd type ipconfig, find IPv4, 
Start the second client, and type [IPv4]:8000, but it isn't connecting to server
```

What have I to do, to make it work?

Here are my code samples:

[Client](https://pastebin.com/jqx4XTCn)

[Server](https://pastebin.com/n2vF1ssM)

If it is needed, I can also share PodSixNet files too.

Comment: Does it works with 2 clients on the server computer ? What kind of wifi are you connected to, home wifi or company one ? I mean, is there any proxy ?

Comment: @B.Barbieri Actually, when there are two clients on a server computer, and they do actions, it crashes, but if not to do anything, then both clients are connected. I tried to use my mobile network, and also company one. I'm zero in computer networks, so I don't know if there's any proxy

Comment: @B.Barbieri Also, I don't know if this information will be useful, but using mobile network I could setup Minecraft server and play it with friend on the second computer. So through mobile network there is a connection for both computers.

Comment: Company wifi probably has a proxy. The issue might be about the server running on le local loopback interface instead of all interfaces. Try to connect to `[IPv4]:8000` from your server computer : if it should fail.

Comment: Just read the last lines of your server.py. Your server is definitly running on the local loopback. Posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After investigationg with you in the comments, it's clear now that your server is running on the **local loopback** (i.e. `127.0.0.1`), therefore you can't access it from another interface (e.g. `[IPv4]`).

When you run server, you should set it to `0.0.0.0:8000` (which means all interfaces, port 8000) instead of `localhost:8000`.

Comment: So, while starting server I should set it to 0.0.0.0:8000, and what I should type while running both clients?

Comment: The server will be listning to all interfaces, so you can use either `[IPv4]:8000` or `localhost` on the server computer. The other one will have to use `[IPv4]:8000`. Note that you can have many IPs if you're connected on several networks : each client will then be able to use the IP matching the network it's connected on.

Comment: I did as follows: server set to 0.0.0.0:8000, then connected on this computer, but when I typed [IPv4]:8000 on the second computer, it wasn't connecting to server

Comment: Thanks, finally it works! But I have another question. Can you tell me ways, in which I can make my server available not only for local computers but also for those somewhere else?

Comment: You'll need to open the right port on your internet box. The procedure depends on your ISP, but a bit of googling will sure show you some good tutorials.